# SQL Case not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

I am trying to cast my result as varchar but it keeps giving me this error,

**Code**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetQuality](@FruitID VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result varchar(200);

WITH 
latest AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Fruits_Crate WHERE FruitID like @FruitID ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) a
), 
result AS
(
    SELECT 
        latest.ExpiryDate as LatestExpiryDate, latest.Size as LatestSize, latest.Weight as LatestWeight,
        previous.ExpiryDate as PreviousExpiryDate, previous.Size as PreviousSize, previous.Weight as PreviousWeight,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, latest.ExpiryDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) As LastMovementInDays,
        COALESCE((Select MovementInMonths from Fruits_Settings Where PolicyID like '178'),3) * 30 AS MM,
        CASE SIGN((latest.Weight * latest.Size) - (previous.Weight * previous.Size))
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Increased'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Static'
            WHEN -1 THEN 'Decreased'
            ELSE 'Static'
        END AS Movement 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Fruits_Crate WHERE FruitID like @FruitID ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) x  ORDER BY ExpiryDate) previous
    FULL OUTER JOIN latest ON previous.FruitID = latest.FruitID
)

SELECT @Result = CAST( 
            CASE 
                WHEN LastMovementInDays <= MM AND (Movement = 'Increased' OR Movement = 'Decreased')
                    THEN Movement
                    ELSE 'Static'
                END) AS VARCHAR
FROM result;            
RETURN @Result

END
```

**Error**

> Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 25 Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', 
>   expected 'AS'.

Issue is with Cast I am trying to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the specify the CAST:

```
SELECT @Result = 
        CASE 
            WHEN LastMovementInDays <= MM AND (Movement = 'Increased' OR Movement = 'Decreased')
                THEN 'Movement'
                ELSE 'Static'
            END
FROM result;
```

Please note that the default string for a `CAST` to a `varchar` is 30 characters. This does not cause problems in your code example, however, as you have defined `@Result` as `VARCHAR(200)` this can result in truncation. Run for example:

```
SELECT CAST('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' AS VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `AS VARCHAR` in `CAST()` function as below

```
SELECT @Result = CAST( CASE 
                WHEN LastMovementInDays <= MM AND (Movement = 'Increased' OR Movement = 'Decreased')
                    THEN Movement
                    ELSE 'Static'
                END AS VARCHAR) 
FROM result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
END) AS VARCHAR
```

to this one:

```
END AS VARCHAR)
```